# using indices among data frames in r

Tags: r

I have two data frames:

```
d1 <- data.frame(x1 = c(0,10,10,20,2,2,6),
                 date  = c(3652,3652,3653,3654,3655,3656,3657))

d2 <- data.frame(rat = c(1.2,1.3,1,1,1.2,1.3),
                 date = c(3652,3653,3654,3655,3656,3657))

> d1
  x1 date
1  0 3652
2 10 3652
3 10 3653
4 20 3654
5  2 3655
6  2 3656
7  6 3657

> d2
  rat date
1 1.2 3652
2 1.3 3653
3 1.0 3654
4 1.0 3655
5 1.2 3656
6 1.3 3657
```

I would like to create a new column in d1 that is the value that we get by dividing d1$x1 with d2$rat for a specific date.

For example, the outcome I would like here would be

```
> d1
  x1 date x1_rat
1  0 3652 0
2 10 3652 8.3
3 10 3653 7.69
```

and so on...

these are calculated as 0/1.2, 10/1.2, 10/1.3 and so on...

How can this be done? I'm basically treating 'date' as an index  to know which values in d2[,1] to use to divide d1[,1].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `match` to identify the row of `d2` corresponding to each row of `d1`:

```
d1$x1_rat <- d1$x1 / d2$rat[match(d1$date, d2$date)]
d1
#   x1 date    x1_rat
# 1  0 3652  0.000000
# 2 10 3652  8.333333
# 3 10 3653  7.692308
# 4 20 3654 20.000000
# 5  2 3655  2.000000
# 6  2 3656  1.666667
# 7  6 3657  4.615385
```

A similar approach that's a bit messier would be to use `merge` on the two data frames and then compute the ratio.