# Replacing a string with a matched number in a column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in R with 10,000 columns and roughly 4,000 rows. The data are IDs. For example the IDs look like (rs100987, rs1803920, etc). Each rsID# has a corresponding iHS score between 0-3. I have a separate data frame where all the possible rs#'s in existence are in one column and their corresponding iHS scores are in the next column.  I want to replace my 10,000 by 4,000 data frame with rsIDs to a 10,000 by 4,000 data frame with the corresponding iHS scores. How do I do this?

This is what my file looks like now:

```
input ID     match 1    match 2     match 3 ......
rs6708       rs10089   rs100098    rs10567
rs8902       rs18079   rs234058    rs123098
rs9076       rs77890   rs445067    rs105023

This is what my iHS score file looks like (it has matching scores for every ID in the above file

snpID     iHS
rs6708    1.23
rs105023   0.92
rs234058  2.31
rs77890   0.31

I would like my output to look like 

match 1   match 2   match 3
0.89      0.34      2.45
1.18      2.31      0.67
0.31      1.54      0.92
```

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Or just use `merge()`

Comment: This question has the same general format http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613579/using-indices-among-data-frames-in-r

Comment: @PierreLafortune yeah, I guess the difference here is that Evan has multiple columns of IDs to match, but the solution of using `match` or `merge` is basically the same.

Comment: @josilber your new solution builds on the other well. +1 And yes, an example from OP would def help.

Comment: Hey, I edited my post, is that good now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider a small example:

```
(dat <- data.frame(id1 = c("rs100987", "rs1803920"), id2=c("rs123", "rs456"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
#         id1   id2
# 1  rs100987 rs123
# 2 rs1803920 rs456
(dat2 <- data.frame(id=c("rs123", "rs456", "rs100987", "rs1803920", "rs123456"),
                   score=5:1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
#          id score
# 1     rs123     5
# 2     rs456     4
# 3  rs100987     3
# 4 rs1803920     2
# 5  rs123456     1
```

Then you can do this operation with:

```
apply(dat, 2, function(x) dat2$score[match(x, dat2$id)])
#      id1 id2
# [1,]   3   5
# [2,]   2   4
```

The call to `match` figures out the row in `dat2` corresponding to each id in your column.

Comment: I edited my original post, does this answer still hold?

Comment: @Evan yes, my posted code finds the matching scores. It looks like you've edited a completely new question at the bottom, which is not good practice on this website. Please instead use the "Ask Question" button to ask your new question about fitting normal distributions based on the matched data.

Comment: My bad, I took it off. Can you explain what the number 2 specifies?

Comment: @Evan it means you fall the specified function on each column of `dat`. To operate on rows instead you would use 1 instead of 2.